# Учебники по Java

Tags: java, книги

Здравствуйте, начал изучать Java и не знаю с его начать, очень много технологий, сложно выбрать что приоритетней.  Cам я скачал недавно с торрентов большой архив учебников по Java, сейчас читаю Thinking in Java 4th Edition, далее по плану JDBC, а вот дальше уже не знаю в каком направлении двигаться. Меня интересует в основном Java для Web - разработки(особенно интересует разработка с использованием MVC) и Enterprise разработки тоже. P.S опыт программирование есть, пишу на C#, каждый год перечитываю, Томас Кормен "Алгоритмы: построение и анализ" так что попрошу советовать только учебники по теме. Если учебник на английском  языке, то это даже приветствуется,  заранее спасибо.

Comment: да, ещё интересует аналоги WCF в Java и учубники но ним

Comment: А, я так понимаю, WCF - это аналог EJB? Копайте только в EJB3, не ранее. Или это просто веб-сервисы какие-то? Я не до конца понял.. определение в википедии какое-то расплывчатое. Если просто обычные SOAP-вебсервисы, то тогда вам надо JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам интересует Java для Web-разработки, то советую копать в сторону обычной JavaEE без всяких наворотов вроде JSF, Struts или Spring. Это поможет понять, как это работает. После этого, могу порекомендовать копать в сторону Spring 3, а потом Spring MVC 3 (только 3, ниже не стоит и смотреть).

Есть ещё целый кусок всего вокруг Java Persistence API (JPA). Это тоже большой кусок знаний, который может пригодиться.

К сожалению, не могу порекомендовать конкретные книги, так как сам я получил большинство знаний самостоятельно. Но кругом полно примеров кода и туториалов, которые мне помогали. По JPA 2 есть книга, которая так и называется: [JPA 2](http://www.amazon.com/mn/search/?ref_=nb_sb_noss&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Pro%20JPA%202%3A%20Mastering%20the%20Java%28TM%29%20Persistence%20API&x=0&y=0&rd=1). По Spring MVC есть тьюториалы, которых вполне достаточно, чтобы понять что к чему, если вы уже понимаете JavaEE (ту часть, которая про веб).

Для Enterprise разработки возможно также понадобятся EJB3 (редко, но вполне возможно), [Oracle Coherence](http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-Coherence-3-5-Aleksandar-Seovic/dp/1847196128/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321168164&sr=8-1) и, может быть, Oracle NoSQL (книг насколько я знаю пока нет).

Есть ещё старая книжка под названием Горький вкус Java. Приёмы, описанные в ней (те что касаются веб-части и JSP) устарели, но идеи актуальны и ошибки, на которые указывает автор остаются неизменными. Стоит прочесть, тем более что книжка тоненькая.

Удачи

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать то, что помогло в свое время мне: [Студенческий отдел кадров](http://java-course.ru/students/students.php) от AntonSaburov.

Кроме того, на хабре есть интересные статьи в этом направлении, например [эта](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/111102/).

Answer (score 0):

Советую данные книги, основы основ.

Java 2. Библиотека профессионала. Том 1. Основы (Авторы: Кей С. Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл)

Философия Java (Автор: Брюс Эккель)